# outlook.office365.com IMAP connect timed out

Tags: java, ssl, outlook, office365, jakarta-mail

- We have wrote java code which extract inbox email from any IMAP/POP3 mail server.
- For email inbox fetch process ,each time the IMAP/POP3 mail server connection is re-opened (close and open).
- This scenario is running properly continuously, suddenly the session connect method throws an ‘IMAP connect timed out’ error message.
  Reading the javax.mail documentation, we have opened JavaMail API session debug messages

**environment specification:** 
-- javax.mail-1.4.3 version.
-- JRE - jdk1.8.0_45

How can I understand why the ‘outlook.office365.com’ mail server suddenly (it’s not a network configuration problem cause we have already connected) throws a new timeout exception?

```
 2017-05-21 03:09:54,201 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - IMAP DEBUG: IMAPProtocol noop
2017-05-21 03:09:54,201 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,201 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A7 NOOP

2017-05-21 03:09:54,219 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A7 OK NOOP completed.

2017-05-21 03:09:54,219 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A8 CLOSE

2017-05-21 03:09:54,239 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A8 OK CLOSE completed.

2017-05-21 03:09:54,239 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
2017-05-21 03:09:54,239 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,239 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A9 LOGOUT

2017-05-21 03:09:54,260 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - * BYE Microsoft Exchange Server 2016 IMAP4 server signing off.
A9 OK LOGOUT completed.

2017-05-21 03:09:54,260 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: IMAPStore connection dead
2017-05-21 03:09:54,260 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,260 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
2017-05-21 03:09:54,260 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,260 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: IMAPStore cleanup done
2017-05-21 03:09:54,260 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.3
2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
2017-05-21 03:09:54,263 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,264 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
2017-05-21 03:09:54,264 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,485 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [SwBMADEAUABSADAAMgBDAEEAMAAwADAAMQAuAGEAcABjAHAAcgBkADAAMgAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]

2017-05-21 03:09:54,486 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A0 CAPABILITY

2017-05-21 03:09:54,498 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.

2017-05-21 03:09:54,498 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN
2017-05-21 03:09:54,498 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,498 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH2
2017-05-21 03:09:54,498 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,498 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=dlpadmin.sg@sembcorp.com, password=<non-null>
2017-05-21 03:09:54,498 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,498 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN

2017-05-21 03:09:54,510 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - + 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,510 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - ZGxwYWRtaW4uc2dAc2VtYmNvcnAuY29tAGRscGFkbWluLnNnQHNlbWJjb3JwLmNvbQBTZW1iQzBycCEh

2017-05-21 03:09:54,756 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.

2017-05-21 03:09:54,756 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A2 CAPABILITY

2017-05-21 03:09:54,781 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION BACKENDAUTHENTICATE CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.

2017-05-21 03:09:54,781 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN
2017-05-21 03:09:54,781 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,781 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH2
2017-05-21 03:09:54,781 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,781 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
2017-05-21 03:09:54,781 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,781 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A3 SELECT INBOX

2017-05-21 03:09:54,846 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - * 0 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 14] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 2813] The next unique identifier value
A3 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.

2017-05-21 03:09:54,846 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A4 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL

2017-05-21 03:09:54,865 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - * SEARCH
A4 OK SEARCH completed.

2017-05-21 03:09:54,865 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A5 CLOSE

2017-05-21 03:09:54,885 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A5 OK CLOSE completed.

2017-05-21 03:09:54,885 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
2017-05-21 03:09:54,885 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,885 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
2017-05-21 03:09:54,885 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:09:54,885 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A6 SELECT INBOX

2017-05-21 03:09:54,916 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - * 0 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 14] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 2813] The next unique identifier value
A6 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.

2017-05-21 03:10:04,916 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - IMAP DEBUG: IMAPProtocol noop
2017-05-21 03:10:04,916 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,916 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A7 NOOP

2017-05-21 03:10:04,935 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A7 OK NOOP completed.

2017-05-21 03:10:04,935 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A8 CLOSE

2017-05-21 03:10:04,955 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A8 OK CLOSE completed.

2017-05-21 03:10:04,955 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
2017-05-21 03:10:04,955 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,955 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - A9 LOGOUT

2017-05-21 03:10:04,974 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - * BYE Microsoft Exchange Server 2016 IMAP4 server signing off.
A9 OK LOGOUT completed.

2017-05-21 03:10:04,974 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: IMAPStore connection dead
2017-05-21 03:10:04,974 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,975 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
2017-05-21 03:10:04,975 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,975 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: IMAPStore cleanup done
2017-05-21 03:10:04,975 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.3
2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
2017-05-21 03:10:04,978 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:24,997 [Thread-124] WARN  com.pa.fw.common.mailreceiver.IMAPMailProxy - Exception while trying to connect to IMAP connect timed out
2017-05-21 03:10:24,998 [Thread-124] ERROR com.pa.fw.common.mailreceiver.BaseEmailInboxProxy - Fetch new email has been failed:connect timed out[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@c79a1c
2017-05-21 03:10:24,998 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.EmailFetcher - Failed to process email message: This operation is not allowed on a closed folder : [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@9129dc1
2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.3
2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - DEBUG: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
2017-05-21 03:10:35,002 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.LogStream - 

2017-05-21 03:10:55,014 [Thread-124] WARN  com.pa.fw.common.mailreceiver.IMAPMailProxy - Exception while trying to connect to IMAP connect timed out
2017-05-21 03:10:55,015 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.IMAPMailProxy - Failed to connect to email server: connect timed out currently there is no connection
2017-05-21 03:10:55,015 [Thread-124]   mailreceiver.EmailFetcher - Failed to process email message: This operation is not allowed on a closed folder : [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6d810319]
```

Comment: Lots of things can cause timeouts including network problems along any segment, server problems, ...

Comment: The server could be rate-limiting you if you're connecting too frequently.  Or a firewall could be slowing you down to prevent abuse.